# How to create a .NET control with a design-time configuration mechanism?

Tags: .net, vb.net, custom-controls, design-time

I want to create a control which allows a property to be set *at design time* which when set configures the control (i.e. sets a bunch of properties).  Ideally, the configuration whether an instance of a configuration class (a functor), a function, or even a configuration name (i.e. a string) would ultimately execute some code against the control itself.  That code would be written by the developers using the control.  They would define any number of configurations and then in the designer the `Configuration` property of the control would display either a dropdown of acceptable choices or allow the developer to key in some value (e.g. the configuration name).  The desired effect is that setting the property would immediately cause the control to be redrawn in the designer in light of its new property settings.

```
Public Property Configuration As String
    Get
        Return m_Configuration
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        m_Configuration = value
        Dim Configure As Action(Of CustomControl) = Configurations(value)
        Configure(Me) //apply custom code written by user of library
    End Set
End Property
```

I tried creating and loading a Shared dictionary with configurations (used in the above bit of code), but I wasn't able to find a way to allow the dictionary to be loaded by a developer so that his configurations would be already in the dictionary when the above property was set in the designer.  It worked if I defined the configurations in the library itself, but that defeats the purpose of customization.

```
//Where and how would the developer cause this to be executed...
Configurations.Add("DoSomethingWonderful", AddressOf DoSomethingWonderful)

//...so that it would be in place for use at design time?
Me.CustomControl.Configuration = "DoSomethingWonderful"
```

I tried making the property an `Action(Of CustomControl)` and exposing some global actions, but the designer didn't allow this property to be set.  I had hoped the property would display a list of the known `Action(Of CustomControl)` methods.

```
Me.CustomControl.Configuration = AddressOf DoSomethingWonderful
```

I tried making the property take an Shared instance of a configuration class (i.e. [a functor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_object#In_Ruby)), but the designer didn't allow this property to be set either.  Again, I had hoped the property would display a list of known configuration instances.

```
 Me.CustomControl.Configuration = DoSomethingWonderful 'configuration instance
```

Inheriting from the custom control is not an option.  Inheriting and overriding a configuration class would be fine.  Ideally, I'm after the simplest approach that meets the requirements.  All of these approaches would work if we waited until run time, but the key is that we have something that works at design time.

---

Specifically, we have a custom grid control into which we define tons of columns and settings.  We commonly have the need to display an address grid which has a predefined set of columns and settings.  The address grid is used in several places throughout the application.  We have other such grids with predefined columns and settings that are used in application wide.  Developers took to copying and pasting the grid from screen to screen.  This makes sense as management would not want us inheriting different flavors of the base grid (e.g. AddressGrid, PersonGrid, etc.).  The trouble is when we change how we display addresses we have to reconfigure all the address grids across the app.  I have it working now so that if you...

```
 Me.Addresses.Configuration = "Address"
```

...the entire grid is properly configured.  The only issue is that we don't want to store the configurations in the control library itself.  The individual applications should be defining their own configurations.  The hosting app just needs a means of relaying these configurations to the library/grid class so that when the above property is set in the designer the library recognizes the configuration and updates the designer appropriately.

Comment: Does this really need to be in the designer? You seem to want a programatic way to configure a control... And you have that, it's the codebehind. You can apply whatever configuration method you like right after InitializeComponent().

Comment: Unless you intend to write your own designer I assume you want to use some existing design tool. However, you have not specified which. In Visual Studio you have Windows Forms and WPF.

Comment: Our shop prefers properties to be set in the designers so that design-time forms look like they're going to look at run time.  If we wait till run time to set such properties, the designers won't match.

Comment: @IliaJerebtsov - wouldn't code behind involve inheritance?  The given control is already used extensively across the organization in hundreds of forms.  Management is not going to allow the type to be changed.  All we can do is add a feature to the current control.

Comment: @MartinLiversage - if only the application using the library had some way of invoking code in the library at design time, I'd have a workable solution.  I certainly don't want to write my own designer.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you have a library, that contains control that has a few public properties, that can be set in the designer. You want to allow the consumers of your library to define standard sets of property values, that can be applied to the control at design-time.

You want to do this because it's of great importance that the controls in the designer should look the same as at runtime, and you don't trust the consumers of your library to apply the control settings correctly on a per-property basis.

There's an inherent paradox in what you're asking, because you're hoping to get your library to run arbitrary external code, that might not even be compiled yet. Designer configuration code is actually interpreted by Visual Studio.

There are a few control libraries (eg: [DevExpress XtraGrid](https://www.devexpress.com/products/net/controls/winforms/grid/)) that can save and restore layout using a XML file. These work at design-time to set the various properties of a control to a previously saved state. In order to implement something like this, you'd have to make a designer extension for your control. [This article contains documentation on how.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0fd17t9s.aspx)

But in reality, you're just going to go through a lot of work for very little actual benefit.

One hack around this would be to just have a library of snippets that programmers can just manually paste into the Form Designer generated code.

Comment: I added more information to the bottom of the question.  Maybe I was too narrow in avoiding the specifics.

Comment: Loading column settings from XML files (or some other format of your choosing) seems like the way to go. See the answer for a link on how.